# Limiting and queueing the database connections

Tags: mariadb, max-connections

In mariaDB, is it possible to do something like this?

- limit the number of connections (like in mysql, as explained in [this SO answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35248/133693))
- set up a queue for all the other connection attempts, and avoid triggering `User ** already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections`

If something like this is possible, is it even **advisable** to set things up in this way?

Real case scenario is that something is causing one of our servers to clog up, with mariaDB taking up as much as 80% of CPU and about the same percentage of RAM. `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` returns a ridiculous amount of connections from one user (+50), while the other users have 3-5 simultaneous connections. If the offending user is temporarily blocked, everything returns to normal.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Our suggestions will assist with reduced time to complete query requests.  WAIT time will be less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the [old resource limits](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35248/133693) inherited from MySQL, [MariaDB grant](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/#resource-limit-options) limits can include `MAX_STATEMENT_TIME` (in seconds), for each query.

There is also [wait_timeout](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#wait_timeout) and [interactive_timeout](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#interactive_timeout) to ensure that idle connections terminate.

[max_session_mem_used](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#max_session_mem_used) limits the memory usage of each connection.

Having a total [max_connections](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#max_connections) within the scope of the server's ability is a good move too.

There's no separate queue option, however hopefully with the `*_timeout` options there is less chance of hitting the limit unexpectedly.

Answer (score 2):

`max_connections` sets a limit.  `back_log`, in theory, provides a queue of pending connections.

But, in reality, you should change your clients to be less demanding.  If you let hundreds of connections in, MariaDB starts stumbling over itself.  Have you ever been in a small convenience store with a hundred other customers?

If it is just one offending client, see `max_user_connections`.

80% of RAM is normal.  80% of CPU may not be good.  Find the slowest queries and work on speeding up (or eliminating) them.