# How to get rid of "maximum user connections" error?

Tags: mysql, php, mysql-5.1, mysql-5, max-connections

I am using MySQLi for my webapp but whenever I want to visit some particular page, I get `mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (42000/1203): User ***_user already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections`.

I tried already to close all connections but this does not improve the situation.

Is there a way to know exactly what connections are open at any particular moment or any other useful data that can help me resolve this issue ?

BTW, I'm using PHP 5.2.17 and MySQL 5.1.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The option [max_user_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections) is a limit imposed, not on the total number of simultaneous connections in the server instance, but on the individual user account.

Let's say the user is called `db_user@localhost`. You can find out what this user's connection limit is by running this query:

```
SELECT max_user_connections FROM mysql.user
WHERE user='db_user' AND host='localhost';
```

If this is a nonzero value, change it back with:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO db_user@localhost WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
```

or

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET max_user_connections = 0
WHERE user='db_user' AND host='localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This will cause `mysqld` to allow the user `db_user@localhost` to use the global setting [max_user_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections) as its limit.

Once you get to this point, now check the global setting using

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_user_connections';
```

If this is a nonzero value, you need to do two things

**THING #1** : Look for the setting in `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
max_user_connections = <some number>
```

comment that line out

**THING #2** : Set the value dynamically

```
SET GLOBAL max_user_connections = 0;
```

MySQL restart is not required.

## CAVEAT

I have discussed this setting in the past

- `May 24, 2011` : [What are user connections - when are the created and destroyed?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2899/what-are-user-connections-when-are-the-created-and-destroyed/2900#2900)
- `Jun 16, 2011` : [Would it be sensible to create a MySQL user for each user account of a web application?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3345/would-it-be-sensible-to-create-a-mysql-user-for-each-user-account-of-a-web-appli/3348#3348)
- `Mar 22, 2012` : [How can I limit MySQL connections?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15426/how-can-i-limit-mysql-connections/15427#15427)
- `Feb 22, 2013` : [Mysql : Maximum number of connections on a per user basis - Possible?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35183/mysql-maximum-number-of-connections-on-a-per-user-basis-possible/35248#35248)

## Give it a Try !!!